# MatLab not formating doubles as expected in matrix

Tags: matlab

I am solving a system of linear equations. I want to output the variables with their respective solutions, displaying decimals (a double).

```
[A,B] = equationsToMatrix(eqs,vars);
res = [transpose(vars) double(linsolve(A,B))];
```

The value of `transpose(vars)` is:

```
Ax
Ay
Az
Md
Me
```

And the values of `double(linsolve(A,B))` is:

```
-75
450
-75
450
183.71
```

However when I concatenate these to vectors, I lose the decimal places, and irrational numbers are converted to fraction/symbolic form with radicals. The output of `[transpose(vars) double(linsolve(A,B))]` is:

```
[ Ax,        -75]
[ Ay,        450]
[ Az,        -75]
[ Md,        450]
[ Me, 75*6^(1/2)]
```

How do I achieve an output with doubles? I want something similar to the following output:

```
[ Ax,   -75.00]
[ Ay,   450.00]
[ Az,   -75.00]
[ Md,   450.00]
[ Me,   183.71]
```

Comment: What is the problem of 450 vs 450.00?

Comment: No. 75*6^(1/2) vs 183.71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vpa` before concatenation:

```
[transpose(vars) vpa(linsolve(A,B))]
```